# EXASOL export to csv with quotes

Tags: sql, csv, export, quotes, exasolution

I want to export a database-tab to csv-file with quotes arround any string (column separator is ";"). This is what I want as csv file (without header): 
"abc";"blabla"

When I export just with "Select * from...", no quotes surround the string:
abc;blabla

When I export with "Select concate('"',column1,'"'), concate('"',column2,'"') from...", following content is given in csv-file:
"""abc""";"""blabla"""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the EXPORT options

COLUMN DELIMITER and DELIMIT to control how the data is exported - e.g.

```
EXPORT RETAIL.ARTICLE 
INTO LOCAL CSV FILE 'C:\TEMP\testexp1.csv' 
ROW SEPARATOR = 'CRLF' 
COLUMN SEPARATOR = ','
COLUMN DELIMITER = '"'
DELIMIT = ALWAYS;
```